# Direct connection to ip camera using android without router

Tags: android, ip-camera

My ip camera is [D-Link dcs 932L](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/products/dcs-932l-day-night-cloud-camera). I'm using [android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dlink.mydlink&hl=en) provided by D-Link to connect to ip camera with ethernet cable or using wi-fi with making some settings. But my problem is direct connecting without router. In addition the dlink light app doesn't allow wireless settings.